# How do I get text in my html page to display features using the css stylesheet?

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

So I'm going through web design more in detail and by all means the text in my page should be size 20. I don't want to use html tags or javascript to make the text size 20. I want to use css. For some reason my index.html file
http://obesechickenapps.com/myhomepage/

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="stylesheet" rel="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
<!--<style>
p{  font : 20pt Arial,geneva,helvetica;}
</style>-->
</head>
<body>
<p>left</p>
<p>middle</p>
<p>right</p>
</body>
</html>
```

does not pick up on the css styling in
http://obesechickenapps.com/myhomepage/stylesheet.css

```
p{  font : 20pt Arial,geneva,helvetica;}
a{  font : 20pt Arial,geneva,helvetica;}
```

When I put the styling in inline style tags then everything works. I'm so confused...
My text does show up as 20pt font Arial.

Why does the css for this page work:
http://obesechickenapps.com/3ColumnsExample/sample3ColumnsPageCss.html
but the first link I used did not?

TL;DR help with linking css stylesheets and html please.

[image: I hate screen readers]

Comment: Should be `[rel="stylesheet"]` and `[type="text/css"]`, but really you don't even need the `[type]` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="stylesheet.css" />`

HTML and CSS are real funny when it comes to the `<link>` property, if even one thing is wrong, the stylesheet won't load at all.

Comment: @obesechicken13 Heh, don't worry, it happens to all of us! :D